# 404 Error on Calling API in production server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-web-api2

I have an web application in which I have integrated Web API into it. Created Route and when called from localhost it works.

When It is moved to production server it works. But when SSL certificate is added and modified web.config to redirect to HTTPS, the Web API stops working in Server.

It throws 404 - File or directory not found.

API Controller:

```
[Route("api/dashboard/{id}")]
[HttpGet]
public DataTable getDashboardDetails(int ID)
{
}
```

Web.config used
HTTPS method:

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^localhost(:\d+)?$" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Web.config -> WebServer:

```
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="managedHandler,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />

      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />

      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />

    <add name="ApiURIs-ISAPI-Integrated-4.0"
     path="/people/*"
     verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"
     type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
     preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("api/{*pathInfo}");
```

Global.ascx.cs

```
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

      GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

Also tried removing the https data from web.config file but it throws 404 error.
Please help to get the api to work in server also.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What bindings do you have setup in IIS

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. The error is because of renaming the project.

Here is another scenario which might confront this error. If we rename our project so that the file name of the assembly changes, it's possible for us to have two versions of our ASP.NET assembly, which will reproduce this error.

The solution is to go to bin folder and delete the old dlls. (I tried "Rebuild Project", but that didn't delete 'em, so do make sure to check bin to ensure they're gone)